Extract some sections from a external tex?
I have a large source tex, structured by sections, and I need to extract a lot of them to a new file. The goal is doing the same as the function \input, but only with some selected sections, not the whole document. I've prooved with the extract package, but I need to have numbered enviroments. I've also tried de exercisebank package and also need the enviroment exercise and it even didn't work on my case.
EDITED
I have this in a data.tex file:
\documentclass{report}
...
\begin{document}
\section{section1}
Here is the text of Section 1

\section{section2}
Here is the text of Section 2

\section{section3}
Here is the text of Section 3

\section{section4}
Here is the text of Section 4

\end{document}

and I want to obtain another file, output.tex, with something like this automathized, for example.
\documentclass{report}
...
\begin{document}
\section{section2}
Here is the text of Section 2
\section{section3}
Here is the text of Section 3

\end{document}

I tried to do that with extract package and also with exercisebank package, but it doesn't work for me. It's a very large tex with a lot of sections and I need to do it. Each section has subsections, pictures, equation and text.

welcome! right now, your question isn't very clear and probably can't be effectively answered. can you provide the code for a small but minimal document we can compile to reproduce the situation you want help with (an MWE or minimal working example)? that would make it easier to help and more likely any answers you receive will actually be of assistance. it isn't obvious this is really a tex question since it sounds as if you want something like gawk rather than tex?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you for your answers. I've edited the original message

Maybe you could add some tags to your data file and use https://ctan.org/pkg/catchfilebetweentags to extract the parts you like?

Thank you samcarter. I have to do this like 6000 times (changing the tag number). Is there any other solution? Or a way to authomatic add the tags?

Thank you John. Could you please put an example? I need some particular sections

Is 6000 the total number of sections, or the number you want to copy?

Imagine something like I have 6000 sections, but today I must pick 500, tomorrow other 600, just in case. I have put an answer to the topic below

I found a solution, is not elegant, but it works.
I have put this in the data.tex file:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[active,generate=FileOutput,extract-env=flushleft,flushleft-nrs={2,3}]{extract}
\begin{extract}
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\end{extract}
…

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}\section {section1}
Here is the text of Section 1

\end{flushleft} 
\begin{flushleft}\section {section2}
Here is the text of Section 2

\end{flushleft} 
\begin{flushleft}\section {section3}
Here is the text of Section 3

\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}\section {section4}
Here is the text of Section 4
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}

And the output file is like this:
%% 
%% This is file, `FileOutput.tex',
%% generated with the extract package.
%% 
%% Generated on :  2024/08/02,18:24
%% From source  :  data.tex
%% Using options:  active,generate=FileOutput,extract-env=flushleft,flushleft-nrs={2,3}
%% 
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
…

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}\section {section2}
Here is the text of Section 2

\end{flushleft} 
\begin{flushleft}\section {section3}
Here is the text of Section 3

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}

